# Can this fopen code be improved

Tags: php, file, fopen

I'm seeing that this code first creates the file, closes it, then opens it with `'a'`, writes to it, then closes it. Is there a way to simplify it. The idea is that if the file name exists, it needs to be overwritten. I also don't understand the point of `unset`. Is it necessary?

```
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'w');
fclose($fp);
unset($fp);
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'a');
fputs($fp, "sometext");
fclose($fp);
unset($fp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From php.net, under the 'w' mode in fopen: *Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.*

In other words, open for writing, and overwrite or create as necessary. No need to use append mode.

```
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'w');
fputs($fp, "sometext");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: "The idea is that if the file name exists, it needs to be overwritten."

Comment: @zerkms Exactly, at the beginning, I'm creating it and overwriting anything that may have the same name. Then from that point after, I'm just writing to the file.

Comment: sorry, I should sleep. You only need to call fopen with 'w' then. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php and scroll down to the 'modes' section.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents($file_name, 'sometext');
```

And, No, `unset()` is pointless in your case.

Comment: So file put contents creates the file if it doesn't exists?

Comment: @sameold: yes it does: "If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flags is set. "